# easy slider doesn't work until function is called twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-load, easyslider

I am using easy slider inside with content loaded with Jquery.load() that is called when you click a thumbnail on my portfolio page. The problem is that the first time you click the thumbnail and load the content the slider doesn't work, but if you close the div with the slider and reclick the thumbail to reopen it it starts working. I have a feeling it has to do with the Jquery.load(). here is the website [iancramergraphics.com/new](http://iancramergraphics.com/new)

sorry this is my first time posting in a forum, so i'm stil getting used to the best way to present my question. i haven't created my own js fiddle before either and i'm not sure how i could include my jquery ajax call. here is my .js and html (i hope this is enough to help you understand)

​

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var id = $(this).attr("id");

$('.thumbnails div').click(function() {

    $('.portfolioDisplay').slideDown('fast');
    $("#slider").load('portfolio/' + id + ".html #slider > *");


    $("#slider").easySlider({
        continuous: true,
        nextText: "",
        prevText: ""
    });
}
});​
```

i tried moving the easyslider declaration right inside the (document).ready and no luck

THANK YOU

the html didnt post on the last one. here it is

```
<div class="thumbnails">
<div id="zubrickyremodeling"><img src="images/thumbnails/zubricky.png" alt="Zubricky            Remodeling" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It will be good if you paste some code. Even better if you post a fiddle.

Comment: Please don't expect us to dig through your site's code.  Also, when you fix the problem, there will be nothing useful here for future readers.  Please post the relevant code _along with_ a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: It sounds like the _initialization_ of the plugin, which normally occurs on `document.ready` is actually occurring on `load()` instead.  Then only after the `load()` is the plugin ready for use on subsequent clicks.  That's as far as I'm willing to go without seeing a [concise self-contained example](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 0):

You are binding plugin on dinamically loaded content, you need something like this http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery (pretty much lightweight)

then you can do:

```
$("#slider").load(url);

$.livequery(function(){
$("#slider").easySlider({
        continuous: true,
        nextText: "",
        prevText: ""
    });
});
```

or better (should work) using ajax without the plugin i linked to:

```
$('.thumbnails div').on('click',function() {
    $.ajax({
    url:'http://www.yoursite.com/portfolio/' + id + ".html #slider > *",
    type:'GET',
    data:{},
    dataType:'data',
    error:function(){},
    beforeSend:function(){},
    success:function(_data){
    $('.portfolioDisplay').slideDown('fast');
    $('#slider').html(_data);
     $("#slider").easySlider({
            continuous: true,
            nextText: "",
            prevText: ""
        });
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i got it working. i couldn't get the plugin to work or the second set of ajax code(i'm sure either would work,but i couldn't get it right), but your second response showed me that i have to use the .ajaxComplete event. this is what i came up with:

```
    $('.thumbnails div').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

$("#slider").load('portfolio/' + id + ".html #slider > *");
        $('#slider').ajaxComplete(function(){
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            continuous: true,
            nextText: "",
            prevText: "" 
        });
```

and this worked. thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't get the plugin or the second set of code you suggested to work(i'm sure just because of my inexperience with ajax), but you made me realize i had to use the .ajaxComplete after the .load. this is what i came up with:

```
    $('.thumbnails div').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");

    $("#slider").load('portfolio/' + id + ".html #slider > *");
        $('#slider').ajaxComplete(function(){
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            continuous: true,
            nextText: "",
            prevText: "" 
        });

        });
    });
```